# When I save a photo from photo library to Documents it is blank when I read it

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I know I must be missing something in this code. If it has already been asked I don't know what term to search for.  I searched about read picture in document folder blank, or empty. I knew it wasn't nil because Xcode said that it could not be nil for that type (UIImage).

I am able to use imagepicker to get a picture and display it in a UIImageView. When I save the UIImage into the Documents folder there is no error.  However, when I read that saved image and try to display it in a UIImageView the picture is blank, or empty (it just shows the background color of the View.)

I am able to copy some pictures from the contents folder in the app into the Documents folder and they display properly.  I went through and added print statements throughout the code to see if there was a place code was being skipped.  I even wrote a function to list the filenames in the Documents folder.  The names of the pictures are there, but the data for the picture that I would save doesn't seem to have been written.

```
 func addNewPhoto() {
    gotAPicture = true
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self

        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    var newImage: UIImage
    if let possibleImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        newImage = possibleImage
    } else if let possibleImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        newImage = possibleImage
    } else {

        return
    }

    let imageName = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".jpg"
    let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if let pictureData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.9) {
        pictureData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
    }

    ChosenImage.image = newImage

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    picker.delegate = nil
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

I have checked the code, rewritten it, and started from scratch.  I even followed coding examples from hackingwithswift.com in lesson 10 (as well as other tutorials).  That lesson ended up working once I changed the .allowsEditing to false.

OK, here is the code that I use to display the picture

```
@IBOutlet weak var ChosenImage: UIImageView!
```

And, here is the code I am using to read the pictures in the Documents folder. It is in a different view controller and the outlet is called mainImage.

```
let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let path = getDocumentsDirectory()
    let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path as String)

    imageList.removeAll()
    currentImage = 0

    for item in items {
        if item.hasSuffix(".jpg") {
            imageList.append(item)
            }
    }

    mainImage.image = UIImage(named: imageList[currentImage])

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipeRight(_:)))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipeLeft(_:)))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipeUp(_:)))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
```

What is causing the data of the UIImage to not get written along with the filename? I am sure that I missed something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use this kind of initialisation for image like `let image = UIImage(named: <#imageName#>)`, because this kind of initialisation better use only for images that exists in your application bundle. I suppose that you will suit with method like 
 `let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: <#imagePath#>)` for clearance that you load images, that you persist earlier.

However, you problem is simple, when you get your contents of directory, the output will like that

`21AB15AE-D69A-416B-AE93-6DC334E41F91.jpg
6CB9FA7B-FF20-4D60-B7EB-B44300C85AF9.jpg
86508AEC-AE8B-4FB8-8CA5-307DF58E959A.jpg
9C90944E-87EE-4B41-BA99-A6A8171402AC.jpg
AC2BC0D4-CA51-4A24-9D80-87F8736A72A7.jpg
B0C772A6-8354-4C7C-B23B-7414123E52FB.jpg
B10FE95C-E017-411C-BAD1-986A6090F463.jpg
DCB4B0C9-DDB4-4188-8DF7-0ABFD2FD76CB.jpg
EEDDCABD-A707-4CAA-9AF7-5009EAA57FA8.jpg` and so on...

That leads to main problem - you try to load images *just by referring to it only their name*, and that produce nil-image as result. To load image you should specify full path to image (full-path will work both for *contentsOfURL* and *named* initializers)

I'd create simple project, you can get it [here](https://github.com/igorkislyuk/image-directory-saving)

Comment: Before I look at your simple project I decided to see if I understand what you are telling me.  I came up with a small function to use in my code by way of your help.  
    
func doTheImage() {
        let path = getDocumentsDirectory()
        let imageWhere = (path as String) + "/" + imageList[currentImage]
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageWhere)
        print(imageWhere)
        mainImage.image = image
    }

It works just fine.  Thank you!  (It certainly does not show up formatted properly.  :-/ )